# How to specify oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout in Oracle JDBC connection url?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I am new to oracle and I need to know whether I can specify the following properties in the connection URL itself and if you can how you can specify.

oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout
oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT

Following is my JDBC connection string

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localost:1521/oracl`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:< SID >:oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=< timeout-value >;